# Google+ How post message to my page? google-api-php-client

Tags: php, google-api-php-client

I whant post messages to my google+ page from my website. Try simple example.

Code that i have is:

```
<?php 
    require_once 'google-api-php-client/autoload.php'; // or wherever autoload.php is located

    $client_id = '-';
    $client_secret = '-';
    $redirect_uri = 'redirect_uri';

    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setClientId($client_id);
    $client->setClientSecret($client_secret);
    $client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);

    $client->setAccessType('offline');
    $client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login'));

    $client->setRequestVisibleActions(array('https://schemas.google.com/AddActivity'));
    $client->setApprovalPrompt('force');

    if (isset($_REQUEST['logout'])) {
      unset($_SESSION['access_token']);
    }

    if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
      $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
      $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
    }

    /************************************************
      If we have an access token, we can make
      requests, else we generate an authentication URL.
     ************************************************/
    if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
      $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
    } else {
      $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
    }

    if ($client->getAccessToken()) {


        $plusService = new Google_Service_Plus($client);

        //$userinfo=$plusService->people->get('me');
        //print_r($userinfo);
        $moment_body = new Google_Service_Plus_Moment();
        $moment_body->setType("http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity");

        $item_scope = new Google_Service_Plus_ItemScope();
        $item_scope->setId("target-id-1");
        $item_scope->setType("http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity");
        $item_scope->setName("The Google+ Platform");
        $item_scope->setDescription("A page that describes just how awesome Google+ is!");
        $item_scope->setImage("https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/snippet/examples/thing.png");

        $moment_body->setTarget($item_scope);
        $momentResult = $plusService->moments->insert('me', 'vault', $moment_body, array("debug"=>true));
        //print_r($momentResult);

        $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
    }

    if (
        $client_id == '<YOUR_CLIENT_ID>'
        || $client_secret == '<YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET>'
        || $redirect_uri == '<YOUR_REDIRECT_URI>') {
      echo missingClientSecretsWarning();
    }
    echo 
    '<div class="box">
      <div class="request">';

    if (isset($authUrl)) {
      echo "<a class='login' href='" . $authUrl . "'>Connect Me!</a>";
    } else {
      echo '
        <a class="logout" href="?logout">Logout</a>';
    }
     echo "</div>

      <div class='shortened'>";
    if (isset($momentResult)) {
      var_dump($momentResult);
    }

     echo " </div>
    </div>";
```

But it doesn't work. I don`t recive any mistakes. Just empty array of my moment.

> object(Google_Service_Plus_Moment)#19 (13) { ["internal_gapi_mappings":protected]=> array(0) { } ["id"]=> NULL ["kind"]=> string(11) "plus#moment" ["objectType":protected]=> string(29) "Google_Service_Plus_ItemScope" ["objectDataType":protected]=> string(0) "" ["resultType":protected]=> string(29) "Google_Service_Plus_ItemScope" ["resultDataType":protected]=> string(0) "" ["startDate"]=> NULL ["targetType":protected]=> string(29) "Google_Service_Plus_ItemScope" ["targetDataType":protected]=> string(0) "" ["type"]=> string(37) "..." ["modelData":protected]=> array(1) { ["target"]=> array(6) { ["kind"]=> string(14) "plus#itemScope" ["type"]=> string(37) "http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity" ["id"]=> string(11) "target-id-1" ["description"]=> string(50) "A page that describes just how awesome Google+ is!" ["image"]=> string(66) "fhg" ["name"]=> string(20) "The Google+ Platform" } } ["processed":protected]=> array(0) { } }

Hope you can advise where mistake. Thx.

Comment: I think you need to do something like this to post moments $client->setRequestVisibleActions(...)  But remember you cant actually post to your timeline with the Google+ API moments aren't the same thing.

Comment: So i shoud use another method, not a moment?

Comment: It is not possible to post to your Google+ timeline with the Google+ api.  there is no other method.